# Architecture for Cocoa app that uses C-coded TCP server

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, server

I have written application (library) in C language that is TCP server that will be used by mobile apps (Android/iOS) to connect to it. Most of the functionalities of this server is contained inside this C program.

Now I would like to add GUI intereface to this server in order to easly start/stop/restart this server, to configure, or display some information about ip address/port number server is running. Set some password to use to provide basic security.

So I have written such basic status bar application to realize this 
[image: Cocoa GUI app]

Now I consider how to join both apps: Cocoa GUI app, and C server app. I will need to exchange some basic configuration informations between them.

Would it be better to link this C server app as library in Xcode Cocoa app project or just let C server app be standalone app that Cocoa GUI app will only start as separate process (program) and kill it when user click stops. I could pass security password, custom port number to the app as arguments when starting this app. But how could I get information about currently chosen port number to display in my GUI app if the C app using some automatic configuration.

Which solution will be better to manage while developing, code, and then distribute in App Store.

Comment: Implements all the logic in C, add public port and admin port, implement the listening function and use our GUI as a client of the admin part.

Comment: But should Cocoa app be separate and just start/stop TCP background server app with given configuration? OR should I link this server code into Cocoa app and start/stop server on background thread (I think here I have better control on this server in my gui app) Client-side of this server will be library in mobile app (Android/iOS)